# MemoryPuzzle — простая игра в консоли

Tags: c++, ооп, c++11, инспекция-кода, stl

Я тут сделал свою первую нормальную консольную игру на С++. Это простая игра. Игра также известна как Концентрация, Pelmanism, Shinkei-suijaku, Pexeso и Pairs. Это простая консольная реализация этой игры. Есть 3 уровня: легкий, нормальный и сложный. Также после игры отображаются статистические данные (за сколько ходов вы прошли уровень).

Я пытался использовать STL и объектно-ориентированное программирование. Поэтому, прежде всего, я хотел бы знать, как улучшиться именно в этом. Я также хотел бы знать, насколько я понятен и понятен мой код. Буду очень благодарен за все советы!

[Ссылка на github](https://github.com/Starikov32/MemoryPuzzle)

Comment: советую для подобных игр использовать curses - это хорошее решение для разработки интерфейса консольной игры.

Comment: во время игры не получается выйти из нее. Советую сделать C^d сигналом к выходу - это вполне стандартное решение для консоли

Comment: Если нажать клавиши esc и enter когда прога просит ввод - начинается какой-то бесконечный цикл - пофисиксите это

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, не понял на счет C^d, например ^C работает. А на счет выхода, да не продумал)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch не смог повторить проблему с Esc + Enter. ( Win 7 )

Comment: cntr + d - это сочетание клавиш в большинстве консольных прог означает что требуется выход из проги. По сути эти клавиши преобразуются в EOF

Comment: Сначала я выбираю играть (1), низкий уровень сложности, потом нажимаю последовательно клавиши ecs и enter - вы также проверяли?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ок сделаю Ctrl + d, спасибо!

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch и на счет ncurses, тоже спасибо, посмотрел, и в правду интересно)

Comment: и рекомендую все же присмотреться к curses - это отличная библиотека для создания интерфейса консольных программ и проста в освоении. Вот пример: я недавно написал тэтрис для консоли, зацените - https://github.com/andrejlevkovitch/tetris.

Comment: единственный ощутимый недостаток: она разработана на Си (впрочем я начал пользовать ей еще до того, как перешел на С++). Как результат не получится использовать С++-подобный ввод-вывод, а пользоваться встроенным Си-подобным или писать обертку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78787/discussion-between-andrej-levkovitch-and--).

Comment: В ридме стоило описать, какие платформы поддерживаются, какие зависимости, как его собирать, и т.п.

Comment: @VTT, спасибо за комментарий, не знал этого, так как пока что не очень хорошо умею пользоваться GitHub. Применю ваш проект опишу все)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он должен содержать код прямо в вопросе. Вопросы со ссылкой подвержены "протуханию" и бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 0):

В это воскресенье заморочился и написал свою версию этой игры. Ввод-вывод через `curses`, работает под Линуксом и Виндоус, правда что касается последнего - не гарантирую что под ней сможете собрать, поэтому рядом ложу ссылку на скомпилированную прогу. Версия не окончательная, это задел под работу - писал так, чтобы прогу можно было бы по максимуму модифицировать изменяя лишь константы (такие как размер колоды, количество карт, их размер и т.д.)

[github](https://github.com/andrejlevkovitch/concentration.git)

[скомпилированная прога под windows](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H2LC4Fdw73zTM_lVfcxcgfvIbH7bQyTy)

Comment: Интересно, посмотрю!

Comment: @МаркСтариков могу предложить совместную доработку этого кода до уровня полноценной игры. Если тебе это интересно

Comment: Да интересно. Можно сделать.

Comment: @МаркСтариков тогда счас дам тебе доступ к репозиторию

Comment: ок принимаю, где будем обговаривать проект? Slack, Telegram, Viber?

Comment: @МаркСтариков можно в слэке - недавно его завел как раз в этих целях. Найди меня по почте: andrejlevkovitch@gmail.com

Comment: @МаркСтариков еще не нашел меня?

Comment: Нет что то не получается. Похоже забыл уже как им пользоваться)

Comment: Нет что то не получается. Похоже забыл уже как им пользоваться)

Comment: @МаркСтариков дай мне свой адрес

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79441/discussion-between---and-andrej-levkovitch).